# gradle ask recognize the TestIING suite.xml

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm using Gradle 1.7 and Test-ING in my project along with selenium, the problem which I'm facing is that I have defined a xml file for the sequence of tests that I want to take place. The line for the test defined in build.gradle is as follows-

```
test {
  useTestNG(){
  options.suites("src/test/resources/sample.xml") 
}
 }
```

Gradle is unable to recognize the sample.xml file and is not executing any test, its just skipping.
Can anyone please help me in this. I want the tests to be executed in the same order as defined in sample.xml as this already the current implementation of the project which can't be altered.

Comment: Perhaps the `--info` or `--debug` log gives a clue.

Comment: Hey Peter, I tried that but it's not giving any result. I tried both --info and --debug. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: I know too little about TestNG and your specific setup to give advice.